# BizTalk Insert Into Oracle Database - PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here ORA

Tags: xml, oracle, biztalk

I am trying to do an insert from a file to the oracle database. i've mainly folllowed the tutorial i found [here](http://biztalk2010changes.blogspot.be/2011/04/insert-update-delete-select-operation.html). I've done some minor changes to make it an Insert only though, but the Insert sent port picks up the file now but gives the below error.

What could be wrong here or is there a way to check what query is created by this interface?

---

**Input file**

```
<ns0:Insert xmlns:ns0="http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/DCSDBA/Table/V_SIZE">
  <ns0:RECORDSET>
    <ns0:V_SIZERECORDINSERT>
      <ns0:V_SIZE InlineValue="InlineValue_0">V_SIZE_0</ns0:V_SIZE>
      <ns0:SEQ_NR InlineValue="InlineValue_0">10.4</ns0:SEQ_NR>
    </ns0:V_SIZERECORDINSERT>
  </ns0:RECORDSET>
</ns0:Insert>
```

---

**Error message**

```
The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port  

"WcfSendPort_OracleDBBinding_DCSDBA_Table_V_SIZE_Custom" with URL 
"oracledb://redprairie:1521/TST/Dedicated?PollingId=Test". 

It will be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this Send Port.  

Details:"Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.TargetSystemException: 

ORA-06550: line 2, column 78:
PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:

PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored --->  
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-06550: line 2, column 78:
PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.Adapters.OracleCommon.OracleCommonUtils.ExecuteNonQuery(OracleCommand command, OracleCommonExecutionHelper executionHelper)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shold not use inline value. Take a look for using inline [conditions](http://www.biztalkgurus.com/biztalk_server/biztalk_blogs/b/biztalksyn/archive/2008/10/20/when-to-use-inlinevalue-attribute-in-insert-in-oracle-ebs-adapter.aspx)

```
<ns0:Insert xmlns:ns0="http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/DCSDBA/Table/V_SIZE">
  <ns0:RECORDSET>
    <ns0:V_SIZERECORDINSERT>
      <ns0:V_SIZE>V_SIZE_0</ns0:V_SIZE>
      <ns0:SEQ_NR>10.4</ns0:SEQ_NR>
    </ns0:V_SIZERECORDINSERT>
  </ns0:RECORDSET>
</ns0:Insert>
```

Comment: this seems to have worked. the error changed (constraint.) i'll fix that one and accept your answer in a bit.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  the input file was an automaticly generated file in visual studio though, so it's strange it created those inline comments. i will check your link when i get the time.